# MongoDB: How to order the records in results like MySQL fields keyword

Tags: mongodb

I want to order the records in result set. How can I receive the results in MongoDB like what I expected. In MySQL, I can use the following query to get my expected way of sort.

But how can I get in MongoDB.

```
SELECT * FROM fruit 
ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange'), variety;
```

Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: The sort order for results in MongoDB either has to be based on a field present in the documents you are querying, or a field calculated/projected in an [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help:

```
  db.users.find({},{_id:0,"accounts":1,"name":1});
```

But i have never tried ordering fields.

Comment: Thanks! But I want it should be sorted by given order of IDs.